# Sloane1.com: What Is a Persistent Cookie?

Tags: cookies

Sloane International Development: Hey guys I just want to know What Is a Persistent Cookie? as I have no idea about this
Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

**Persistent cookies** – these files stay in one of your browser's subfolders until you delete them manually or your browser deletes them based on the duration period contained within the persistent cookie's file.

**Session cookies** - these are temporary cookie files, which are erased when you close your browser.
(to see the difference between the two types of Cookies).

Source: http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/cookies-the-same.html

And maybe you want to know what Cookies are/do:

Cookies are usually small text files, given ID tags that are stored on your computer's browser directory or program data subfolders. Cookies are created when you use your browser to visit a website that uses cookies to keep track of your movements within the site, help you resume where you left off, remember your registered login, theme selection, preferences, and other customization functions.The website stores a corresponding file(with same ID tag)to the one they set in your browser and in this file they can track and keep information on your movements within the site and any information you may have voluntarily given while visiting the website, such as email address.

Source: http://www.allaboutcookies.org/cookies/

***You should google it next time***